# Most compact way to represent a graph

Tags: optimization, graph

Given these nodes:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

And given some edges between the nodes like this:

```
a/b/c
b/c/d
c/e
c/d/e/f
c/g
f/g
e/f/g
a/c/h
h/a/b
c/a
d/b/c
f/g/c
d/a/f
g/f
g/a/b/c
f/a/b
e/a/c
```

(where a/b/c means one edge from a to b, and another one from b to c), so this describes a directed graph.

Here is another, more compact representation for the same graph:

```
a(b(c(d, e(f), g)))
f(g)
e(f(g), a(c))

...
```

using a tree-like representation. But there are still duplicates in there (e.g. `a` and `c` are shown twice in the last snippet).

Another way to represent it is like this:

```
a:b
a:c
b:c
c:d
c:e
```

But this uses even more letters than the original (first) snippet.

Wondering if there is anything better than these 3 approaches to represent a directed graph.

Maybe there is a way to assign numbers to the letters and do all 3 approaches as one. Or maybe something else.

So what could be a representation using the smallest amount of bytes?

Comment: You only have 8 nodes, so you can trivially store a complete adjacency matrix in 64 bits. Does it need to be smaller than that?

Comment: No there would be billions of nodes, sorry this was just an example.

Comment: OK, so what representations have you already looked at? What properties does your graph have? Do you need edge weights or just connections? Do the edges have direction? What's the ratio of edges to vertices?

Comment: Good questions. I don't know what you mean by graph properties, I am not an expert in graph theory but I have a working knowledge of graphs. No weights necessary. The edges have a direction. The representations I have thought of are what I wrote about in the question, I haven't seen any others. There are let's say an average of 10-20 edges per vertex.

Comment: What do you mean you haven't seen any others? You won't see things unless you go look for them. For example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) describes three representations, and you can figure out for yourself how much storage each will take for your case. Then you can see if there's some way to trim it down further (eg. an adjacency matrix can be triangular - so about half the size - if you don't need direction).

Comment: Those 3 linked to representations are all suboptimal. There are ways to compress it down further that adjacency lists and matrices. Also matrices use too much space since it would be a sparse matrix.

Comment: What does `a/b/c`, followed by `b/c/d` mean?  Is the repeated b/c redundant or meaningful?

Comment: So you _have_ seen other representations, but you don't like them for ... reasons. I don't know how you expect anyone to answer this question satisfactorily when it all your actual requirements are being drip-fed in comments, and your sample representations are so abstract I can't tell how big they would be.

Comment: Your example seems to be a tree, which is a very special graph. Is your question about arbitrary graphs (which means your example representations don't fit well) or just about trees?

Comment: @DocBrown it is about graphs

Comment: So your graphs may contain cycles?

Comment: Yes the graph may contain cycles.

Comment: @LancePollard: I took the freedom and tried to improve your description. Please double check if I got your intentions right.

Comment: @DocBrown oh wow that's really nice of you. It reads much better, thank you so much.

Comment: @ErikEidt: what is so unclear in this question (after my edit and my answer) you choose to close it as "unclear" without even writing a comment? I mean, I can understand the votes which happened before my edit (and those lazy guys which don't come back here to revoke their votes), but your vote came after my edit, so what's the point?

Comment: @DocBrown, I did write a comment asking a question.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I see. Well, I guess after we worked out what OP meant with his graph notation, it is safe to assume "b/c" was just redundant, no hidden agenda behind it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any directed graph with vertices `V={v_1, ..., v_n}` can be identified with a subset of

```
 S = V x V \ {(a,a) | a in V}
```

where V x V means the cartesian product, and each of these subsets represent a different graph. So this means there are 2^(n * (n-1)) different graphs over V. Thus, a uniform representation where each graph takes the same storage size requires necessarily `n * (n-1)` bits per graph. Less is not possible because of the pidgeon hole principle.

Of course, one can find a representation where some graphs over V need far less than `n * (n-1)` bits, but then others will need more. But without any knowledge about which graphs have to be processed or stored in context of a specific use case, or additional constraints (like a limited number of edges), one cannot decide which of these representations will need less or more bytes than another.

For example, one may develop representations where graphs with a smaller number of edges will take less space than graphs with a higher number. For a deeper analysis, you may find [this thesis about compact and efficient representations of graphs](http://lbd.udc.es/Repository/Thesis/1417160280628_thesis_(11).pdf) helpful.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: if instead of an arbitrary graph you have a DAG or a tree, there exist quite effective compression algorithms.